# .Net send mail through Gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

I am trying to send a mail with Asp.Net (MVC3) through an GMail-account i've created. I've crawled the internet for how-to's, but nothing i tried has been working.

I have a method that looks like this

```
public static bool SendEmail(string to,string subject,string body)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("myaccount@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add(to);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = false;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myaccount@gmail.com", "mypassword");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This method returns false when im using it. How can i solve this?

Comment: replace  catch with  catch(Exception e) and then put a break point and see what error it is

Comment: Have you tried this? [http://stackoverflow.com/a/32336/1299332](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32336/1299332)

Comment: Is outbound port 587 open on YOUR (and/or the webapp's) firewall?

Comment: You can start by not swallowing exceptions. Then read the duplicate question's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I verified the following works:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //create the mail message
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("your.email@gmail.com", "yourpassword"),
        EnableSsl = true
    };

    //set the addresses
    mail.From = new MailAddress("your.email@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("to@wherever.com");

    //set the content
    mail.Subject = "Test subject!";
    mail.Body = "<html><body>your content</body></html>";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    client.Send(mail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding this line

```
 smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```